# How to find the centre of the circle that inscibes an isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I encountered this problem in the "Elementary Geometry for College Students" book.

[Diagram of a trapezoid (according to the book)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7owyA.png)

Some definitions from the book:

- When all vertices of a quadrilateral lie on a circle, the quadrilateral is a cyclic quadrilateral
- A trapezoid is a quadrilateral with exactly two parallel sides
- If the two legs of a trapezoid are congruent, the trapezoid is known as an isosceles trapezoid
- An isosceles trapezoid is cyclic

The book describes the process as such: "the center of the circle containing all four vertices of the trapezoid is the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of any two consecutive sides (or of the two legs)."

I simply do not understand their instructions, I tried drawing a couple of diagrams as well as searching the net, but no luck. Sometimes the centre is found outside the trapezoid, which makes things even more confusing.

Could you help me understand the steps from their description (an image would be much appreciated) or maybe there is an easier algorithm, I would be interested in that too.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is something wrong here, we know that for 3 non-collinear points passes a unique circle that contains these 3 points. As you are working with any trapezoid, we can move that fourth point to our liking, so that we can make the circumference leave or leave it inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since the trapezoid is inscribed into a circle, each side is a chord in that circle. The center of a circle does lie on a perpendicular bisector to any chord (because the center is equidistant from the ends of the chord). So you need to take two chords, draw perpendicular bisectors to them and the point of intersection of the bisectors will be the center. The center can be inside or outside of the trapezoid. You cannot use both bases as the perpendicular bisectors will coincide (i.e. you will not get a point of intersection).

Comment: From what I understood, you are saying that the two bases of the trapezoid will be the two chords. If I draw perpendicular bisector to the two chords (bases), it will be just a straight line through the trapezoid (so no intersections). Could you provided a picture of your steps?

Comment: @V3HjtoTs: I added a picture and an explanation why you can't use two bases. Any other pair of sides will work.

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes sense now!

Comment: Thank you. I had reversed in my mind the prostapheresis formulas between the sum and difference of sines.